# How to compare two lists and write the differences to a file? Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list, compare

```
masterlist = ["subdomain.com", "subdomain2.com", "subdomain3.com", "subdomain4.com","subdomain5.com", "subdomain6.com"]

originaldomains = ["subdomain.com", "subdomain2.com", "subdomain32.com", "subdomain43.com","subdomain55.com", "subdomain6.com"]
```

Write differences from both lists into a file.

```
   # Combine these into a masterlist
    masterlist = list1 + list2


    if os.path.exists('masterlist'):
        print('Overwriting masterlist')
        with open('masterlist', 'r') as f:
            originalsubs = f.readlines()
```

I have masterlist as var1, and original subs as var2.

I want write the differences (hopefully) in my same code block of my if statement? If possible?

Comment: Sorry about that, I was being lazy here, I properly put the quotes around the values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in lists can be quickly achieved using [Python Sets](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).  It's worth knowing how these work.

```
masterlist = [ 'subdomain.com',  'subdomain2.com',  'subdomain3.com',  'subdomain4.com', 'subdomain5.com',  'subdomain6.com' ]
originaldomains = [ 'subdomain.com',  'subdomain2.com',  'subdomain33.com',  'subdomain44.com', 'subdomain5.com',  'subdomain6.com' ]

# get the differences
master_set   = set( masterlist )
original_set = set( originaldomains )
difference_set = master_set.symmetric_difference( original_set ) 

# write to a file
fout = open( "diff.txt", "wt" )
for item in difference_set:
    fout.write( item + "\n" )
fout.close()
```

I've purposefully not written this to a "finished homework assignment" standard.  Please read the linked documentation, and use it to understand the code.  Then write your own solution.